# Sorting algorithm is activated only after refresh

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

My code sorts the my collection, but If I make an admin to change someones rank, the change only gets activated after a refresh. Am very confused as to why, and how to fix this, any help would be awesome!

```
Meteor.publish("sortingAlgo", function(){
    return og.find({},{ sort: {rank: 1,scores: 1}});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're also sorting on the client after you subscribe. In publications, `sort` is mostly useful when used in conjunction with `limit`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, I tryed this code on the client: const handle = Meteor.subscribe('sortingAlgo');
        Tracker.autorun(() => {
          const isReady = handle.ready();
          console.log(`Handle is ${isReady ? 'ready' : 'not ready'}`); 
          if(isReady){
              return og.find({},{ sort: {rank: 1,scores: 1}});
          }
        }); and it didn't change

Comment: That really should work - how are you rendering the results? React? Blaze?

Comment: Yup, I'm using React. So I wait for the collection to load at the start of the render then I put in that code as aforementioned

Comment: What pattern are you following to make your component reactive? react-komposer? Other?

Comment: Ah I've never actually used one I think, I just thought that by using meteor and that it uses web-sockets and such that it would do it all for me, my bad. So the code sorts it, but only after refresh, do I need react-komposer for it to update automatically after I make a change in the admin?

Comment: Oh and by the way just thought I'd mention I am using TrackerReact whether that makes any difference

Comment: React-komposer is one pattern, the meteor guide recommends using [createContainer](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#data)

Answer (score 0):

You publication code is right.

You need to sort the value on client side as well. Because whenever you add a new doc its update the publication. But on the client side your value is append in you mini mongo.To fix this you need to sort the data on client side before using this.

//Subscribe your publication.

```
Template.name.helpers({
    'data: function() {
        return og.find({},{ sort: {rank: 1,scores: 1}});
    }
})
```